# After updating screen no longer locks

Tags: 16.04, power-management, xfce, lock-screen

After upgrading to 16.04 my screen no longer locks after I leave the computer running without usage.

What do I need to check to see why this happens?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
false
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay
uint32 30
```

Comment: What is the output of: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm See the edit

Comment: Settings seem fine. Not sure if it is going anywhere, but does Ctrl + Alt + L lock the screen?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I just tried it, and nothing happened.

Comment: @JacobVlijm If i go through the menu and select the lock icon, it *does* lock the screen.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I just notice you use xfce, not sure if the keyboard shortcut is the same...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I checked it. It's Ctrl-Alt-Del. I tried it and it locked the screen.

Comment: After what time your screen gets turned off?

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath It doesn't

Comment: Can you change "automatically lock the session option" to other and check? It is under security tab.

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath I'm sorry i don't think i can find that option.

Comment: What happens if you execute `xflock4` from the terminal? @v010dya

Comment: @Fabby Screen locks just fine with the command.

Comment: Is there a file called `xscreensaver.desktop` in `etc/xdg/autostart/`?  If yes, what are the contents?

Comment: @Fabby Yes there is

Comment: Weird...  go to the console [Ctrl][Alt][F1] login there as admin and do: `sudo apt purge xfce4-session` and then `sudo apt install xfce4-session` and then `sudo reboot` and log in normally and tell me what that did. (effectively uninstalling the screensaver, re-installing and rebooting)

Comment: @Fabby tried... but didn't help

Comment: @Fabby I found the solution, i think that you were the closest one with trying to reset the configurations of xfce4-session, but apparently it didn't reset some of them. If you will post the answer, hopefully giving some rational explanation of why this has happened i will happily give you the bounty.

Comment: You took a different approach to me ending up with the same result: it works.  I would have reset all of the xSreeenSaver settings next, you just took light-locker, bypassing the xSreeenSaver settings.  Upvoted both Q and A already before posting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i have managed to find the problem. Thanks to all the people who have tried to give me hints in the comments, but in the end it was something completely different. I will post that as an answer, hoping that at least one person will benefit from that somewhere in the world.

I have found that in the Settings Editor within `xcfe4-session` -> `startup` -> `screensaver` -> `type` i had `xscreensaver`. So i have attempted to install it and it actually turned on. But the lock screen at the end was clearly not from XCFE, that gave me an idea to change `xscreensaver` in the settings to `light-locker`, and now i have just tested it and it works.

[image: Settings Editor - session configuration]

Answer (score 1):

XFCE uses the `xfce4-session` Window manager and the `xscreensaver` and there seems to be something wrong in your settings which I cannot locate exactly, so from a console:

```
sudo apt purge xfce4-session
sudo apt purge xscreensaver
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install xfce4-session
sudo reboot
```

this will purge all of your screensaver-related settings and reinstall everything and should bring you back to the default state.

**Note:** Going to the first console is accomplished by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: I actually had to remove `xscreensaver`, xfce uses `light-locker` instead.